# How to change the keyboard layout of a UWP app in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms-styles, xamarin.forms.entry

I am working on a Xamarin Forms app which I want to deploy on Windows (UWP). The current problem I am trying to solve is to set the keyboard layout on an "Entry". According to the [docs](https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/controls/choose-keyboard-for-entry/) the only change I have to make is to add a "keyboard" property in the Entry xaml code like that:

```
 <Entry Keyboard="Numeric" />
```

That does work fine in Windows Mobile Emulator and the keyboard does change as soon as I click on the entry. However, when I run the project on a Surface Pro tablet (UWP) the layout of the keyboard does not change at all.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On tablets, no matter if it is an iPad or a surface, the Keyboard property is ignored. On a phone it is not.

So you have no chance to influence it on a tablet.