# How to get numeric keyboard for Windows tablets?

Tags: windows, xamarin.forms, uwp, keyboard

I want numeric keyboard for Windows tablets. I used code

```
Keyboard="Numeric"
```

but it gets numeric keyboard for Android devices, iOS devices and Windows phone. It doesn't bring numeric keyboard for Windows Tablet. I refered [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46413795/how-to-change-the-keyboard-layout-of-a-uwp-app-in-xamarin-forms) it says that getting a numeric keyboard in tablet is not possible. I want to know is there any way I can get this feature. Maybe using custom renderer or dependency injection. If so how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is known issue and it has fixed in latest version, please update Xamarin.Forms nuget package version to latest stable version(contained in the UWP client project)

[image]

**Update**

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Entry), typeof(MyEntryRenderer))]
namespace App10.UWP
{ 
    public class MyEntryRenderer : EntryRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (Control != null)
            {
                Control.InputScope = Element.Keyboard.ToInputScope();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!!! Is there anyway I can do this without updating my Xamarin forms package?

Comment: Sure, you could custom Entry renderer like above.

Comment: Zhu  is it possible to get keyboard which shows only numbers? Right now I used both Telephone and Numeric keyboard but it's showing special characters aswell.

Comment: emm, The keyboard is provided by system, I have not found pure Numeric keyboard within tablet. so, I think it could not display pure Numeric .